# Remove a sub-string from a log using grok pattern in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have log file content as follows:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2017.11.06",
  "_type": "kafka-jmx",
  "_id": "AV-QGz3xU0bFuxdeGGWp",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "metric_value_number": 1,
    "path": "/Users/nishantsingh/JMX_CONFS/",
    "@timestamp": "2017-11-06T06:53:44.937Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "localhost",
    "metric_path": "localhost_9999.KafkaActiveControllerCount.Value",
    "type": "kafka-jmx"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1509951224937
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1509951224937
  ]
}
```

I am trying to write a grok pattern similar to

```
filter {
  grok {
      "metric_path" => "%{GREEDYDATA}\.%{JAVAMETHOD:metrictype}\.%{JAVACLASS:metricname}"
  }
}
```

i need to actually get rid of `localhost_9999` substring

Comment: You should use [the gsub option of the mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub).

Comment: yep.. works,, but why not grok

Comment: Because grok does not remove content from one field. It reads one field, compare it to a regex and if it matchs, assign new fields with values read from the field. For example, in your question, the grok example at the end: 1) read the field `metric_path` 2) compare it to the regex built with the pattern 3) If it matches, assign the values to the fields `metrictype` & `metricname`. But the field `metric_path` is unchanged.